# Sql syntax error while doing left outer Join in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I'm using oracle database and trying to delete duplicate records from that.
For the same I've written a below query but getting this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
```

Its giving red indicator under `outer` keyword in `Left outer join` in query.

Query:

```
DELETE FROM Duplicate LEFT OUTER JOIN (

   SELECT MIN(RowId) as RWID, STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ROLLNO, STUDENT_SUBJECT
   FROM Duplicate 
   GROUP BY STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ROLLNO, STUDENT_SUBJECT

) as KeepRows ON
   Duplicate.RowId = KeepRows.RWID
WHERE  KeepRows.RWID IS NULL;
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> Oracle; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Also, just a post of code doesn't make a question. Put the information we need in your question; along with what you've done to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not permit `JOIN`s in `DELETE` queries.  This is clear if you look at the syntax diagram for `DELETE` in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8005.htm#i2112830).

There are many ways to rewrite this using a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  The safest is probably the `NOT IN` method proposed by Ankit because it works even when the columns are `NULL` and `rowid` cannot be `NULL`.

I will point out that for a large number of records, it can be faster to empty the table and reload it:

```
CREATE TABLE nodups as
    SELECT d.*
    FROM duplicates d
    WHERE D.ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowId)
                          FROM Duplicate
                          GROUP BY STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ROLLNO, STUDENT_SUBJECT);

TRUNCATE TABLE duplicates;  -- backup first!

INSERT INTO duplicates
    SELECT *
    FROM nodups;
```

Answer (score 2):

What I can guess is that you are trying to delete the duplicate records from the `Duplicate` table. Your syntax doesn't seem correct from Oracle perspective. You may try below query -

```
DELETE Duplicate D1
 WHERE D1.ROWID NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowId)
                          FROM Duplicate
                         GROUP BY STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ROLLNO, STUDENT_SUBJECT)
```

Comment: Yes this one of the possible solution of problem, but what's wrong with my query ..?

Comment: Any suggestion ..?

Comment: Just run the query I posted. This is the correct Oracle supported syntax.